# Cast from bytearray to hexa Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app which receives a continuous flow of data using ble, at this moment I properly read the flow sent by the device, but in fact I don't know how to interpret it.

This is my onCharacteristicChanged function

```
    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?
    ) {
        if (characteristic != null && characteristic.properties == BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) {
            Log.e(TAG, "**THIS IS A NOTIFY MESSAGE")
        }
        if (characteristic != null) {
            data = characteristic.value
            Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "Datos:")
            Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "$data")
            val dataparsed = data?.joinToString ( " : " )
            Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "$dataparsed")
            broadcastUpdate("com.np.lekotlin.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE")

        }
    }
```

This function is called every time the device sends me some info, returning an exit like this one:

[image]

Where we can see two interpretations of the same data

The data without treatment (the bytearray):
[B@ ****
And the data after the joinToString (function I thought it would help me casting into hexa):
** : **: **: **: **: **: **: **: **: ** <-- But here there are negative numbers!!

My problem comes when I compare this output with the returned by another software I am using, CySmart

Which returns me something like

```
07:94:02:5A:56:00:76:35:00:00

07:2F:02:5F:45:00:B0:36:00:00

07:E4:01:50:47:00:6D:37:00:00

07:0C:02:53:4A:00:56:38:00:00
```

This output obviously follows a pattern, the first 7 and the 2 last group of 0s, for example but the negative numbers are baffling me.

So, in summary, my question is, exist any native way in kotlin to cast from bytearray to hexa? (without negative numbers)
In case I'm already casting it properly do you figure how can I treat, or which is the patron with the negatives numbers? It seems like 2's complement or something like that, but I don't know it surely.

Lots of thanks in advise.

Comment: `negative numbers are baffling me` — JVM uses signed numbers for everything, and for signed number most significant bit "shows" sign of the number (0 — positive, 1 — negative). So if you just look at unsigned number as signed, everything higher than 127(0111 1111) would be negative.

Comment: Thanks, but for example how can i interprete -91, for example? like 1001 0001 ? or? Sorry im a little bit confused

Comment: I already know the theory of 2s complement, but im referring at how should i treat this numbers: -91 in binary is -1011011, in 2s complement i obtain 0100101, and then i should i pass to hexa? like obtaining 25 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already mentioned having a negative number in a byte array only means that the number is larger than 127.

As for your question on how to display them as hex, you can use the built-in string formatting functions. You can add a transform block to your `joinToString` call which can convert your byte to a hex string:

```
val dataparsed = data?.joinToString ( " : " ) { "%02x".format(it) }
```

This way your output will be formatted correctly.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was searching for, lots of thanks!